# Suggestion to create Android layout dynamically from database

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say I have a layout like this:

[image]

Creating the layout is not complicated, **if** the questions are fixed. But my requirement is to display the questions from database, like this:
[image]

As you can see, there are 4 sectionIds. That means we have 4 categories. I'm thinking to use LinearLayout for this. Then for each categories, we have different amount of questions. If the question type is R, use RatingBar. But if the type is D, then use TextArea. I also plan to use LinearLayout for each questions. Now the challenge is creating those layout dynamically, which I think is not that easy. What's the least complicated way to do this?

Comment: Use ReyclerView with multiple views and Just implement `getItemViewType()`

Comment: I won't back the recyclerview recommendation, because that will give you a list, but not a form

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this in several opportunities, so I wish I can give a tip or more:

If your problem is not complex, look for something that has already solved it:

This [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5162) create a layout based on Firebase data
This [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6761) is for creating forms

Most of the times, any library will work because programmatic views are tight to specific requirements, so you will have to go on your own.

### Customized Solution

Creating programmatic views it has a skew learning curve but with time you will be able to solve it.

#### Defining your fields:

Create fields or partial package and put those classes inside. You want to create a class for each type of field so you can reuse easily and modify it is done in that class.
Also, define what is common for every field. You can do this with an interface:

```
interface FormField {

   String result();
   boolean isValid();
   void setError();

}
```

In this case, this interface will allow you to handle the result of the field, know if it is valid and set the errors. Validations should be inner once are requested, and error should be settable do internal validations and from outside.

The result you are getting can change by specific methods in other classes but having a common String is most of the time useful even for showing a summary to the user.

There is another benefit, you can create a list of your fields by your interface, every fields implement it:

```
List<FormFields> fields = new ArrayList();
//fields.add(ANY CLASS THAT IMPLEMENTS THE INTERFACE);
```

#### Creating a Field

Start by creating a class that extends a suitable view for your field:

```
public class InputText extends EditText implements FormFiel {
      //You can simply add customizations in the constructor
}

public class InputText extends LinearLayout implements FormField {

    //Maybe you need an input with a label, hence a TextView and an EditText will go inside of this

}
```

The rule of thumb for this task about constructor is **one param for java two params for xml**. So wherever you need to put the view, you use either one of those.

#### Handling Field appearance

If you need something simple maybe just set everything in the constructor.

```
public class InputText extends EditText implements FormField {
          //You can simply add customizations in the constructor

    public InputText(Context context) {
         super(context)
         setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent...)
    }

}
```

if you need something more complex use the layout inflater.

```
public class InputText extends LinearLayout implements FormField {
          //You can simply add customizations in the constructor

    public InputText(Context context) {
         super(context)
         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
         //You have to create the layout, a neat trick is create it inside a linear layout eand then use refactor/extract
         //The last boolean in the method attach it to the view
         layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.field_input_text, this, true;)
         //Maybe you want to find something, this could be a field variable
         TexteView tv = this.findViewbyId(R.id.inside_the_inflated_layout)
    }

}
```

#### Define a model

You need to define a model for all the field types

```
public class FireField {

    private String label, hint, type;
    // Empty constructor and getters and setters

}
```

#### Create a Container class

The container class probably is a linear layout with orientation vertical, you want to create it anyway and added in the xml (remember 2 params constructor) so you can add inside that view a way to get all your fields, a special method for that.
It can be a list of fields, it can be the list of the data you need to send.
This way, fiedls take care of their own logic and form take care of the general logic.

#### Add the views

You have to fetch your data then do a loop and for each type of the data, add a new view, this is when the `List<FormField>` of views come in handy, following is pseudo code

```
List<FireField> data = new ArrayList();
//You can also have String, View map here, where the key is the type and the value View is your field
List<FormField> fields = new ArrayList();


for (DataSnapshot children: snapshot.getChildren()) {
    FireField field = children.getValue(FireField.class);
    data.add(field);
    if (field.getType.equals("INPUT_TEXT)) {
        //Here Im addinf the field in the constructor, then the view should take care of it
        new InputText(context, field)
        //Here I'm initializing the view, the view inside that method should set labels and other
       InputText input = new InputText(this);
      input.initialize(field);
       fields.add(input);
        //You can add it here or in other place re using some of the lists above
        container.addView(input);
    }
}
```

Finally use any of the list and the container method to get the data and send it to Firebase